# Sum IFs of total count without recounting Multiple instances, only the closest date prior to the AS OF DATE

Tags: excel, sum

I need a formula that will SUM the amount of, let's say, animal types AS OF DATE given WITHOUT adding the previous animal type count, only for the closest date prior to or on the AS OF DATE. Different animal types maybe added to or taken away. So list is not set.

I prefer not to do this in VBA or with a Pivot Table, But any help will be appreciated.

```
    A            B          C
 DATE        ANIMAL TYPE  COUNT
 JAN 01        DOG          1
 JAN 02        CAT          2
 JAN 04        Fish         1
 JAN 12        DOG          2
 JAN 20        CAT          3
 FEB 01        PIG          1
 FEB 02        CAT          2



 AS OF DATE TOTAL ANIMALS
 JAN 03          3
 JAN 13          5
 JAN 21          6
 FEB 01          7
 FEB 02          6
```

So.

As of Jan 03, there was 3 animals total. 1 Dog and 2 cats.

As of Jan 13, there was 5 animals total. 2 Dogs, 1 Fish and 2 Cats,,,,,, NOT 6

As of Jan 21, there was 6 animals total. 2 Dogs, 1 Fish and 3 Cats,,,,,, NOT 9

As of Feb 01, there was 7 animals total. 2 Dogs, 1 Fish 1 Pig and 3 Cats, NOT 10

Comment: Are these actually dates, or strings?

Comment: @A.S.H Yes these are actual dates.

Answer (score 1):

So far this is what I have. By using a helper column to filter the Animal Types I get a list without duplicates. Then I put that in a cell with Data Validation to pick the Type. Same for the Dates. However I would like to drop the Type input and just choose the Date. And be able to get a total.

Here is what works but not what I need.

```
=SUMIFS(TabData1[Count],TabData1[Date],MAX(IF(TabData1[Animal Type]=$G$2,IF(TabData1[Date]<=$F$2,TabData1[Date]))))
```

I want to do away with the Single Cell reference **($F$2)** of a single Animal Type and replace it with a Range to get the latest count of Animals for all Animal Types as of a certain date. Like this but this does not work.

```
=SUMIFS(TabData1[Count],TabData1[Date],MAX(IF(TabData1[Animal Type]=(OFFSET($J$2,0,0,COUNT(IF(ListAnimalType="","",1)),1)),IF(TabData1[Date]<=$F$2,TabData1[Date]))))
```

To simplify **(OFFSET($J$2,0,0,COUNT(IF(ListAnimalType="","",1)),1))** you can use **$J$2:$J$5**

```
=SUMIFS(TabData1[Count],TabData1[Date],MAX(IF(TabData1[Animal Type]=$J$2:$J$5,IF(TabData1[Date]<=$F$2,TabData1[Date]))))
```

And it looks like this

```
=SUMIFS(TabData1[Count],TabData1[Date],MAX(IF({"Dog";"Cat";"Fish";"Dog";"Cat";"Pig";"Cat";0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}={"Cat";"Dog";"Fish";"Pig"},IF(TabData1[Date]<=$F$2,TabData1[Date]))))
```

Like I said, I want **one** formula that will take each Animal Type find the latest date from a specified cell and return the sum for each Animal Type then sum them all up.